# Facebook fan page app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

I've built a few facebook apps using the c# sdk. and using code below to check if the user has liked the fan page and showing content to reflect that.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["SignedRequest"] != null)
    {
        signedRequest = Session["SignedRequest"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        signedRequest = Request.Form["signed_request"];
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signedRequest))
    {
        dynamic SignedRequestData;
        var DecodedSignedRequest = FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest.Data;
        SignedRequestData = DecodedSignedRequest

        var RawRequestData = (IDictionary<string, object>)SignedRequestData;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> paird in RawRequestData)
        {
            Response.Write("key =" + paird.Key.ToString() + " value =" + paird.Value.ToString() + "<br/>");

        }

        if (RawRequestData.ContainsKey("page"))
        {
            Facebook.JsonObject RawPageData = (Facebook.JsonObject)RawRequestData["page"];

            if (RawPageData.ContainsKey("liked"))
            {
                if (bool.Parse(RawPageData["liked"].ToString()))
                {
                    LikedContent.Visible = true;

                    if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                        PageSetup();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UnlikedContent.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UnlikedContent.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DefaultContent.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DefaultContent.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that if i have multiple pages on the app i get cross domain issues. can fix this quite easily for ie using the p3p header in the gloabl.asac.cs file.
the issue however still remains in safari.

Now that the current version 6 of the c# sdk recommends using the facebook javascript sdk to call the open graph and check that the user likes a page and then pass it to the code behind i was wanting to know what actually is the best practice for building facebook fan page tab apps?

When ever i access the users information using the javascript sdk i get a pop up box to authorise the app. i don't want this. is there a way round this?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call graph api method like this in code behind

```
void CallFacebookApi(string oAuthToken, string userId)
{       
string userLikeUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/Likes/" + pageId +"?access_token=" + oAuthToken;

  response = requestFBData(userLikeUrl);
  if (response.Length > 0)
    {

     JObject userLike = JObject.Parse(response);
     int count = userLike["data"].Count();

     if (count > 0){
     //user liked your page.
     } 
     else {
      //user do not liked your page yet
      }
    }

 }

public string requestFBData(string action)
{
   string results = string.Empty;

    try
    {
     HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
     HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
     results = sr.ReadToEnd();
     sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      if (e.Message.Contains("400"))
      {
       //invalid reponse
      }
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Comment: do i need tpass string oAuthToken, string userId from the javascript sdk code on the frontend? do you know if this will cause cross domain issues.

Comment: since this is the back-end code you can get oauth_token and user_id by parsing signed_request

Comment: ok so the same way i've been doing before? i havent tried this yet but i think this will cause the same cross domain issues, as i'm aware the signed_request does not persist across multiple pages so you have to store it in a session. which safari hates

Comment: Yes you were parsing it right but why cant you save access_token and user_id in session ? if you do not want to keep it in session you can have this in url in app_data

Comment: saving it session causes the the cross domain cookie issue in safari. you get the same issue in ie but that can be solved by adding a p3p [link]http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/09/27/3282.aspx.  i will look into putting it in the app_data of the url of the tab. thanks